# Issues with rJava and Terminal inputs for Mac

Tags: java, r, macos, terminal, rjava

I am trying to update RJava to reflect the latest version of Java 1.8 on my mac. I think I found the right information in doing so but the issue arises when I use 'Terminal' to run some code. I have to run:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf -n
```

but I receive an error of:

```
sudo: R: command not found
```

I found some information online and I found out I need to change the path in Terminal. I found out that the path where R is '/usr/bin/R'. When I changed the path using the command:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/R:$PATH
```

and then tried to run the code again; I got no where and I am out of luck. I don't understand what the code is but I can only assuming what it does. Hopefully I can get some insight on how I can change the path so I can update rJava to the updated Java Version. Thank you for anyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PATH` setting would be `PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` or you even easier

```
 sudo /usr/bin/R CMD javareconf
```

Note that `-n` wouldn't do anything so you probably didn't mean that. Also if you don't even have `/usr/bin` on your `PATH`, you have probably even bigger issues since you also need to find `java` in the first place. In cases like that you may have better luck using `sudo -i` and then using the shell to fix whatever env vars are not setup correctly in your system.

Comment: Hi,
Unfortunately it seems that I don't have '/usr/bin' in my Path. I'll use sudo -i and try fixing it from there. Thank you for your time.